# How to detect SCTE35 in HLS live stream in Shaka Player

Tags: http-live-streaming, shaka, scte-35

I am using Shaka Player with mux.js to play HLS live streams. I want to detect SCTE35 when they are added to the stream. Can we add any event listener for the the same?

Answer (score 1):

This has been discussed in the Shaka Player GitHub and it is not yet supported, I believe - you could register your interest there as it is not high priority at the moment:

- https://github.com/shaka-project/shaka-player/issues/4853
- https://github.com/shaka-project/shaka-player/issues/1983

Note there is a suggested workaround, which is essentially watching for segments and then parsing them yourself, but I suspect this is not what you were looking, or hoping, for.